# Join 2 tables with same field names

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables :

```
authors
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+
| id        | int(6)       | NO   | PRI | 
| name      | varchar(255) | NO   |     |
| age       | varchar(255) | NO   |     |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+

books
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+
| id        | int(6)       | NO   | PRI | 
| name      | varchar(255) | NO   |     |
| pub_date  | datetime     | NO   |     |
| author_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | 
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+
```

I'd like to get the author information with his last written book information.
Something that would look like that :

```
{
  name:"Tolkien",
  age:null,
  last_book:{
    name:"The Children of Hurin",
    pub_date:"2007"
  }
}
```

For now I am doing it that way :

```
Select Aut.name, Aut.age, Book.name AS Book_name, Book.pub_date 
FROM authors AS Aut 
LEFT JOIN books AS Book ON (Aut.id=Book.author_id) 
WHERE Aut.name="Tolkien" 
ORDER BY Book.pub_date DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

This means that I have to process the result and then order it to have the json that I showed previously.

Comment: so...what's wrong with this?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to return a MySQL result set as a JSON string? That is usually done in the code that processes the result set.

Comment: Is there a way of doing it without post processing? If I had more fields, the query would become much bigger, because I'd have to rename all the same fields.

Comment: So you want to know how to create a object/model from returned query ?

Comment: I want to know if I can organize the object I am returning from the query without post processing it and get the following structure I described in my question. At moment I get the following object : {name, age, Book_name, pub_date} and I have to process it to get the following : {name, age, last_book:{name, pub_date}}. Not hard or anything, I just want to do if I can do it with the SQL syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way is post-processing, but is not so much if you use `json_encode` for serializing an object:

```
$res = mysqli_query("SELECT ...");
$obj = new stdClass();
if($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)) {
    $obj->name=$row->name;
    $obj->age=$row->age;
    $book = new stdClass();
    $book->name = $row->Book_name;
    $book->pub_date = $row->pub_date;
    $obj->last_book = $book;
}

print json_encode($obj);
```

Comment: Ok thank you, I know it's not hard to do, I already did it, I just wanted to know if it was possible without post-processing!